# Getting highest all-time ema value Pine Editor

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to get the highest all-time 200 ema close value in Pine Editor, but I keep getting N/A for the value. My code is:

```
f_highest_since(_highseries,_sinceevent) =>
    var float _peak = na
    _peak := _highseries>_peak or _sinceevent ? _highseries : _peak

f_lowest_since(_lowseries,_sinceevent) =>
    var float _bottom = na
    _bottom := _lowseries<_bottom or _sinceevent ? _lowseries : _bottom

maxema = f_highest_since(ema(close,200), bar_index[0]==0)
```

Interestingly, it works if I replace the ema(close, 200) with something simpler, like close. Does anyone know why this may be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition `bar_index[0]==0` will only be valid for the first bar, and will return false the rest of the time, considering that the first values produced by the function `ema` are `na` it is logical to have `na` as a result.

You might want to use instead :

```
ema = ema(close,200)
max = 0.
max := max(ema,nz(max[1]))
```

Comment: you are welcome, replace all `max` in the code by `min` if you want the lowest value instead.